# iterate through complex multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Here is the output of some complex multidimensional array:

```
    Array ( 
           [0] => Array ( 
                       [@attributes] => Array ( [ID] => 114037469 [Name] => MJBDESIGN.ORG [Traffic] => 4 [BidCount] => 0 [Price] => $8 USD [ValuationPrice] => - [TimeLeft] => 3H 27M [RowID] => 1 ) 
           ) 
           [1] => Array ( 
                       [@attributes] => Array ( [ID] => 114136929 [Name] => TRAININGPROGRAMMEDESIGN.COM [Traffic] => 11 [BidCount] => 0 [Price] => $8 USD [ValuationPrice] => $3 USD [TimeLeft] => 3H 27M [RowID] => 2 ) 
           ) 
)
```

How to iterate through each item and get the 'ID', 'Name' and etc of individual item? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This array is not so much complex.

```
$simpleArray = __YOUR_COMPLEX_ARRAY__;
foreach ($simpleArray as $array) {
    $id = $array['@attributes']['ID'];
    $name = $array['@attributes']['Name'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($array as $r) {
  $name = $r['@attributes']['Name'];
  $id = $r['@attributes']['ID'];
  # code ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you would like all attributes of each row:

```
foreach ($array as $n=>$r){
    echo "Row {$n}\n";
    foreach ($r as $k=>$v){
        // Echo the data
        echo "{$k}=>${v}\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just easy way:

```
$array = // your long array;

foreach($array as $row)
{
    $id = $row['@attributes']['Id'];
    $name = $row['attributes']['Name'];
    // do something with these variables
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like,

```
foreach ($yourarray as $val) {
    echo $id = $val['@attributes']['ID'];
    echo $name = $val['@attributes']['Name'];
}
```

Comment: Why assign aswell as echo?